# How to get the count of number of active client requests for a GET method

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

Is there a way to find the number of active client requests currently accessing a GET method(getProducts()) in REST?

What I have is:

```
@GET
@Path("/products")    
@Produces({ "application/xml" })    
public Response getProducts(){
//My business logic to retrieve products go here
```

}

Now, I issue a GET request from the browser:
http://localhost:8080/v1/products

How to find the number of active client requests currently accessing getProducts() method at any point in time on the server side?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? If you want analytics, you'd better use a dedicated analytics product like Google Analytics instead of polluting your method logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick one:

- Write a Servlet Listener (implementing `ServletRequestListener`) that increments and decrements when the request is initialized and destroyed
- Put the logic of counting directly into getProducts() method
- Create an AOP advice that wraps getProducts() around and increments/decrements when the method is entered and exited

There are tools already written that can measure the performance (and the request counts). One of them: [JETM](http://jetm.void.fm/).

Comment: Writing an AOP advice is overkill for this, especially if he's already not using Spring. The other two are OK.

Comment: Who's talking about Spring? :) Spring is not the only tool that can do AOP. And also.. JAX RS and Spring are not necessarily mutually exclusive (e.g. CXF integrates with Spring).

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev: Will try your suggestion of Servlet Listener implementation.